# Angular - patchValue not working in dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, dropdown, angular-forms

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input placeholder="Select type" matInput formControlName="e_id"
    [matAutocomplete]="cotype">
      <mat-autocomplete #cotype="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
         <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let e of ceList" [value]="e.id">{{e.name}}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Im working on crud operation. During edit, the value is not patching when it is the dropdown and other values are patching in the normal form field...

my **component.ts** is

```js
    getEdit(){
    this.service.getEdit(this.IdValue)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.name = result.name;
        this.e = result.e.id;
      this.EditForm.patchValue({
        name: this.name,
        e_id : this.e,
      })
    })
  }
```